# jQuery GET to API on same domain gives CORS error

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, get, cors

I'm trying to load some data from an API on the same domain. You can find the example at http://bwq.aintno.info/adc_temp. The request starts when the page is loaded, so if you take a look at the console you can see the request failing. However, if I go to the link (http://bwq.aintno.info/ads/api/index.php/specimens) myself in the browser or do a GET request with Postman, it returns the JSON just fine. This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It loads just fine in Chrome. The whole array shows up in the console without errors.

Comment: It also load fine in IE10, the console shows the array without errors

Comment: @WesleyE You're right, it does seem to work in Chrome/Canary incognito, as well as Firefox. The only time it doesn't seem to work is on my regular Chrome or Canary. Maybe it has something to do with my Chrome install/settings? (I think settings get synced across Chrome/Canary?)

Comment: @haiQt try to clear cache data, maybe you are using some old javascript...

Comment: @JonathanNaguin I've already tried that to no avail. Even after clearing the cache the issue remains.

Comment: @haiQt are you probably using `adblock` or a similar plugin ;)

Comment: @t.niese Oh wow, that's exactly it. Disabling Adblock fixed it right away. Do you have any idea what's causing this? This doesn't really seem like wanted behaviour for Adblock...

Answer (score 0):

Out of your comment i know that you use an *adblocker*.

The problem with *adblockers* is, that they block by matching rules, either by url or by certain dom structure (like `class` names or `id`s).

In general if you have a problem with a browsers test it with all extensions disabled. This can (in most cases) be done by using the privacy mode, because many of the *bad* extensions are disabled there. Or using a profile with no extensions installed.

If everything works well there then it is most likely an interfering extension.

In your case the problem is with the url:

```
 http://bwq.aintno.info/ads/api/index.php/specimens
                  ^________^
```

For this portion there is a match rule in e.g. [`EasyList`](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) (`.info/ads/`) - most likely there are similar rules in other lists.

So general having something like `ads` (or similar) with a delimiter before or after is likely to be blocked.

Not only adblockers cause problems with pages there are also other extensions that could cause breaking the page, so you would need to check it agains the commonly used extensions that modify the dom (I know thats not a good news).

But you definitely should check your urls against the the filterlist, and you also could think over checking your dom against it. Or at least avoid urls or `class` and `id` that *sounds* like ads.

One thing that i currently don't know, but what concerned me a little bit right now, is that the rule in easy list is `.info/ads/`. Looks to me as if a request like `script?param=.info/ads/` could also be blocked. Ok this should be escaped anyway but i think i need to add some additional tests to my workflow.